# Find Missing Records From Table A For Table B Where They Don't Exist in Table C

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables:

```
Customer (CustomerID)
CustomerEvent (CustomerEventID, CustomerID, EventTypeID)
EventType (EventTypeID)
```

Some Customer records have some CustomerEvent records with an EventType, some Customer records have no CustomerEvent records.

How do I identify/insert missing CustomerEvent records of each EventType for each Customer record?

My actual issue is a bit more detailed than that, however, this is the piece I'm struggling with.

Can I use one select statement to identify all missing CustomerEvent records? Or would I need to UNION on each EventType record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cross join` to generate a set of all `CustomerId, EventTypeId` and filtering out those that exist in `CustomerEvent` with `not exists()`

```
select c.CustomerId, e.EventTypeId
from Customer c
  cross join EventType e
where not exists (
  select 1
  from CustomerEvent ce
  where c.CustomerId = ce.CustomerId
    and e.EventTypeId = ce.EventTypeId
    )
```

Comment: I had not considered a cross join, that solves it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 

CUSTOMEREVENT CE

left join CUSTOMER C ON C.CustomerID = CE.CustomerID

left join EVENTTYPE ET ON CE.EventTypeID = ET.EventTypeID

where
C.CustomerID IS NULL
OR ET.EventTypeID IS NULL
```